# jspm or npm to install packages?

Tags: npm, jspm

I'm new to jspm, transitioning from npm-only. I have one fundamental question. I have some dependencies in the package.json, and I runned jspm init, which created a nice jspm config.js file. My question is, what it the point of installing these packages from jspm (via `jspm install ...`)? Why not just install them through npm?

More specifically, in my package.json, what's the difference between putting these packages inside `dependencies: {} vs inside jspm.dependencies: {}`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are building a webapp jspm is more suitable for managing your frontend dependencies than npm. I think for a webapp npm only makes sense when used together with [browserify](http://browserify.org/). One key benefit of jspm is that you can load your dependencies using [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) & the [ES6 Module Loader Polyfill](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader).
This enables you to load the dependencies in the browser using the ES6 module syntax.
E.g.:

```
import 'jquery';
```

Keep in mind that jspm is ment to be used for your frontend dependencies.
For your dependencies used for the build process you should keep using npm.

Comment: I can load npm packages with SytemJS too no? That's what I'm currently doing with angular2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs, it's systemJS without jspm.